# Having problems with switch statements

Tags: c++, c, switch-statement

I've been trying to get this code working, but somehow I can't do it..

```
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int a,b,c;
    int y=3;
    int i=2;
    int g[] = {20};
    int m,k;
    int Z;

    printf("Enter a number for a");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("Enter a number for b");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    printf("Enter a number for c");
    scanf("%d", &c);

    m=y;


    do
    {

        Z = a+b-c;

        switch(Z)
        {
        case '0':
        case '1': 
                k=17;
                m+=b;
                break;
        case '2': 
                m+=b;
                m=a;
                break;
        case '3':
                m=a-c;
                m+=b;
                m=a;
                break;
        case '7':
                m+=b;
                break;
        default:
                m=a;
                break;
        }

        g[m] = m%i;
        m--;



    }while(m>b);



}
```

This is the scheme that I had to turn into coding. http://ff.tu-sofia.bg/PIK/Izpiti/MidTest07.html

y and i are 3 and 2 by default, the array g should contain 20 integers, and the users have to type values for a, b and c.

Answer (score 3):

Z is an integer and your cases are looking for strings. get rid of the quotes around the numbers in the cases.

The array g does not contain 20 integers it contains one element 20 in this case. I think what you meant was `g[20] = {}`

Also How is Z calculated ? Is it (a+b)-c or a+(b-c)? You need parentheses to make your intent clearer

```
Z = a+b-c;

 switch(Z)
    {
    case 0:
    case 1: 
            k=17;
            m+=b;
            break;
    case 2: 
            m+=b;
            m=a;
            break;
```

Comment: `'` surrounds a character not a string. The value of char `'0'` is 0.

Comment: You are right it is a char, but '0' is not decimal 0 it is decimal 48 or 0x30.

Comment: Your are right 0 is `nul`. To be fair he didn't state what the error is. This code shouldn't raise a compiler error if that is what he was having.

Comment: The problem isn't that he's comparing to strings (he isn't). He's comparing to `'0'`, `'1'`, etc., which are integer values (of type `int` in C, `char` in C++); they're just the *wrong* integer values.

Comment: Sure, Those chars are integer numbers when it comes down to it, but it seems that is just a mistake to have those quotes, giving the fact that Z is an integer. It would be silly to want to compare to 0x30 and use '0'. Again I'm just pointing out the problems I see we will have to wait to see what the OP meant.